# confusing C syntax

Tags: c

I am reviewing some C code, but having a hard time understanding what Callback is exactly.  Does anyone know what this means?  I'm guessing that it is defining "Callback and x to be  both a void *?

```
typedef void (*Callback)(bool x);
```

Comment: I wanted to point you to http://cdecl.org but it wasn't really up to handling this not very complicated declaration. Weird. One problem is the use of `bool`, but even with `int` substituted it won't work.

Comment: Same - as a command in Linux - cdecl and man pages is http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/cdecl1.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes a new type name `Callback`. Every `Callback` will be a pointer to a function taking a `bool` and returning `void`. In effect `Callback` will be an alias for that real type. So when you say:

```
Callback ptr = some_fun;
```

You're making a function pointer that points at `some_fun`. Function pointers are typically passed to other functions as arguments.

Comment: Callback is a function pointer, not an object. Very important distinction to make.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's true, they're distinct categories.

Comment: Almost. `typedef` never creates a new type; it only creates a new name for an existing type.

Answer (score 2):

It declares a function pointer type by the name `Callback` which points to a function which takes a `bool` input parameter and returns a `void`.
Once you specify the statement, You can use `Callback` as a type to hold address of a function with the specifed type.

Refer the ***[Clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)*** when in doubt.